# Locale not setting on Debian

Tags: debian, locale

I've been having troubles with locales recently. I've been having a problem with them since a long time ago, but didn't bother to fix (dumb me, maybe back then I was closer to solving this problem). Recently I've been trying to code a little bit in Perl, and after running the script an information popped up:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I've been trying to configure /etc/default/locale, adding lines, since I've lurked around other SO's threads:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

To the file, and then running:

> locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

```
But while running this command, I only receive:
Generating locales (this might take a while)....
pl_PL.UTF-8... done     # (which is my native language)
Generation complete.
```

Then I've ran:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

I've chosen en_US.UTF-8 locales to generate, rebooted, bam. Terminal is not opening up. I've changed the default language in settings to Polish, and terminal opened up, but upon starting it a warning popped up:

> bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: can't change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No file or directory

This error was printed in my native language by the way, but I've translated it. Most probably because of the language change.

`locale -a` prints that:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
pl_PL.utf8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It turns out I just didn't have enough locales installed on my system.

```
apt-get install locales-all
```

Solved my problem. For some reason `dpkg-reconfigure locales` didn't work for me.

There is a follow-up question to this problem, since I was scratching my head why the above command didn't work: [Locales were not being generated by dpkg-reconfigure locales](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697827/locales-were-not-being-generated-by-dpkg-reconfigure-locales)

Comment: The SE system is set up for a pairing of Questions with Answers. I'd recommend that you focus this Answer on the resolution to this Question and post any follow-up questions as separate Question(s). Thank you!

Comment: Sure. I will edit that post and post my question once again.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Should/Can I also post a link here in that answer to my next question? Like just by editing that answer. Would that be recommended?

Comment: The general recommendation is to mention this previous question in the next question, to give any additional context for that new question. Thanks!