# Locales were not being generated by dpkg-reconfigure locales

Tags: debian, locale

According to this problem that I've encountered today:
[Locale not setting on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697819/locale-not-setting-on-debian/)

I have solved my problem by running `sudo apt-get install locales-all`.
But one question - what is `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` actually doing? Somebody said (somewhere else on the internet), that it is generating chosen locales. But for me - it wasn't doing anything. The locales were nowhere to be found on the system, thus those lines were popping up:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
```

After running the command once again (`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`) - after installing them by apt-get install of course, and choosing en_US.UTF-8, a message popped up:

```
locales-all installed, skipping locales generation
```

Which is understandable. I have just downloaded a package with all of the locales. So why dpkg-reconfigure locales didn't generate it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I haven't done that before when I was initially solving this problem, but I think the thing is - I haven't uncommented certain locales in `/etc/locale.gen`. I guess this solution will work for some people in the future.

After uncommenting en_US locales (or any others that you would want to be generated) in that file (`/etc/locale.gen`), and using `locale-gen` command it has started generating those locales that I have uncommented. After doing that, I have checked `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and those locales that have been generated by `locale-gen` command were marked with an asterisk (`*`), which means they have been already generated.

So I guess you can do it that way, or just install all of the locales with `apt`.